# UITableViewCell column width change based on screen orientation IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, screen-orientation

I need to make below table like structure in one of the apps I am developing. I am creating this table using UITableView & I need my table column width to change based on the screen orientation. I have set constraints for column width & I will assign values to these using the screen width in my **viewDidLoad()**.

However, I am not able to figure out how to re-align these constraints when screen orientation changes. I figured out that **viewWillTransition()** will be called when orientation is changed & I recalculated the constraints inside that & called setNeedsLayout() for the table view. However, I am not able to make my table view to reset the table column width when screen orientation is changed. I am new to IOS platform and any help will be greatly appreciated.

> HDR_parName/HDR_parValue/HDR_minValue/HDR_maxValue
>
> Para1/value1/minvalue1/maxvalue1
>
> Para2/value2/minvalue2/maxvalue2

Comment: did you add `tableview` `width` constraint?

Comment: Yes, I set the width constraints in story board as Parameter Table View.leading = leadingMargin + 10 and trailingMargin = Parameter Table View.trailing + 10

Comment: You said change width base on ORIENTATION like portrait or landscape mode? But in your comment below, it seems like you want to change width base on the index position of the cell? What **exactly** do you need?

Comment: I needed to set the column width of my table structure based on screen width. I mentioned 10% and 20% calculation in below comment as an example. It seems that confused everyone. The actual calculation is as below. There are 5 labels in my table view cell. The width of label 1 should be 40% of screen width. The other 4 labels should be having width=15% of screen width.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)

    let animationHandler: ((UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void) = { [weak self] (context) in
        // This block will be called several times during rotation, 
        // so if you want your tableView change more smooth reload it here too. 
        self?.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    let completionHandler: ((UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void) = { [weak self] (context) in
        // This block will be called when rotation will be completed
        self?.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition(animationHandler, completion: completionHandler)

}
```

Then tableView datasource and delegate methods will be called, where you can setup elements size according to tableView frame size.

Comment: Hi, It works, but when I click search bar in portrait mode and rotate device to landscape mode then on cancel button my search bar get disappears from table view header view. I am facing this issue for below iOS 11 devices

Comment: @PawanAhire, it's quite difficult to say what causes the problem without code. I think you should create separate question.
My suggestion is that something goes wrong in `tableView dequeueReusableCell`  method.

Comment: Thanks @AlexSh for your quick response. Actually I have added Search controller and Segment control in UIView in viewForHeaderInSection method e.g. 
let headerView = UIView()
headerView.addSubview(self.searchController.searchBar)
return headerView

And for cell:
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell 

Note: I am tapping on Search bar in Portrait and then rotating device to Landscape and then tapping on Cancel button and by doing this my search bar get disappears

Comment: You need to call super somewhere!

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4**

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    let animationHandler: ((UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void) = { [weak self] (context) in
        // This block will be called several times during rotation,
        // so if you want your tableView change more smooth reload it here too.
        self?.yourTable.reloadData()
    }

    let completionHandler: ((UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void) = { [weak self] (context) in
        // This block will be called when rotation will be completed
        self?.yourTable.reloadData()
    }

    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: animationHandler, completion: completionHandler)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple solution, what you are doing is wrong.
Consider you want full width as your row width.

You don't have to set any constraint to cell width, instead set trailing constraint to your tableview. It will handle all.

If you still face similar issue then try

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

let me know if you are still facing the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response Dev. I need to change width of columns inside my table view cell based on screen width. For e.g. width of first column should be around 10% of screen width, second column width should be 20% of screen width etc. So if screen width changes after an orientation change, how can I re-layout my table view?

Comment: apply the above solution to update your view after rotation.

Comment: but if you want cel width like 10% for 1st 20% 2nd then i suggest you to use UICOllectionview. It will be done easily with UICOllectionview

Comment: thanks @Dev_Tandel, i will try this solution and i will let you know.

Comment: Dev its not working that way, everything is coming correctly the first time. But when i change the screen orientation, its not changing the column width as per new screen width.

Comment: bor post screenshot showing your constraints is we can have a look.

Comment: It worked Dev, i had some issues with my constraints, when i corrected those, everything worked.

Comment: Good to hear that..@ArunSreekumar